# Missed dependency in rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run rviz this warning shows up:

```
rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1378871954.108727453]: rviz version 1.10.6
[ INFO] [1378871954.108832285]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1378871954.787439676, 2.340000000]: OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2).
[rospack] Warning: no such package media_export
```

Rviz works fine, but Could be this a missed dependency in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78281/missed-dependency-in-rviz?/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-09-11**:
I'm also getting this issue. And occasional segfaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is due to the rospack library printing to the console where it shouldn't. Please ignore this warning.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1